# Emulate a specific WP device?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm creating an app for Windows Phone 8 that spits out a 1-10 score rating your phone's performance (Like the Windows Experience Index) but for windows phone. The app is basically done, but due to how this app works differently from device to device, I would like to emulate multiple devices in the WP emulator. I own a HTC 8X, and I know my app works fine using that, but how can I emulate another device, such as a lumia 920, using the Windows Phone emulator?

Answer (score 4):

You can't emulate a specific device in the emulator. As a workaround, you can use the [Remote Device Access](http://developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/) provided by Nokia. It will allow you to test the app on a large panel of Nokia phones. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of similar test platforms from other constructors.

Comment: Ok. Nokia owns ~80 of the market, so that will allow me to make some progress.

Answer (score 0):

In the emulator you can test only diferents resolutions and size of rams, i think it would be two of the things you should "scan" in your app so it can help you to test your app

Answer (score 0):

You can test for different resolution and size by this way

[image: For Reference]

But when you need to test mobile like lumia 920 which runs in WP8 os. You need to have WP8 SDk installed in VS2012.